# cpmysqladmin had an unknown error

Tags: centos, cpanel, mysql, whm

I got a dedicated server and I have got WHM installed on the server I have created reseller account on WHM and I was trying to create database using reseller account using cpanel but I am getting weird error message `cpmysqladmin had an unknown error` and also when I try to create users for mysql I got the same error message. does anybody know how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might get a good answer at http://serverfault.com/ also.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I will do it

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue occur to me yesterday... I saw your post and sighed as I saw no response.  I have contacted a friend who works at cPanel and he assisted in resolving the issue for me.

First!  The issue occurred when I updated mysql, after I had an issue of a version mismatch.  I updated it to match up all the version numbers.

To confirm this is the issue, do this:

```
# tail /var/lib/mysql/'hostname'.err
```

*(Replace hostname with your servername.)*

If you see:

```
**[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist**
**[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist**
**[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist**
```

You are in business.

What ended up happening, is a table got lost in the updates.  "mysql.servers"

Options are to manually recreate it *(Don't worry, this table is generally blank on cPanel servers)*

OR

The method I took....

```
# mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=mysqlpasswordhere --verbose
```

The older version of this command would be:

```
# mysql_fix_privilege_tables --user=root --password=mysqlpasswordhere --verbose
```

(This command didn't work for me, I had to use the mysql_upgrade route)

I hope this helps! Enjoy!

PS: The blank table reads as such:

```
# // Column // Type //  Collation // Attributes // Null //

1 // Server_name // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //

2 // Host // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //   

3 // Db // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //   

4 // Username // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //

5 // Password // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //

6 // Port // int(4) // _________________________ // No // 0(DefaultValue)   

7 // Socket // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //   

8 // Wrapper // char(64) // utf8_general_ci // No //     

9 // Owner // char(64) //   utf8_general_ci //  No //
```